# Chromium installed with the snap does not start

Tags: chromium, snap

I am getting error message:
[

```
18905:18905:0317/144624.087334:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(280)] Failed to create /home/alfas/snap/chromium/1043/.config/chromium/SingletonLock: Permission denied (13)
[18905:18905:0317/144624.089911:ERROR:chrome_browser_main.cc(1413)] Failed to create a ProcessSingleton for your profile directory. This means that running multiple instances would start multiple browser processes rather than opening a new window in the existing process. Aborting now to avoid profile corruption.
[18905:19024:0317/144624.095511:ERROR:cache_util.cc(135)] Unable to move cache folder /home/alfas/snap/chromium/1043/.config/chromium/ShaderCache/GPUCache to /home/alfas/snap/chromium/1043/.config/chromium/ShaderCache/old_GPUCache_000
[18905:19024:0317/144624.095610:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(184)] Unable to create cache
[18905:19024:0317/144624.095638:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(606)] Shader Cache Creation failed: -2
```

Comment: Please provide OS/release details

Comment: Ubuntu 19.10. Not sure about chomium version.

Comment: I tried reinstalling, no difference.

Comment: FYI:  If you believe it's a bug I'd suggest reporting it, if I had an issue with a snap (esp. chromium) I'd either use community.ubuntu.com's page for it, or the forum.snapcraft.io page (https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/call-for-testing-chromium-browser-deb-to-snap-transition/11772) where I've usually got pretty quick responses. I'd hoped to have had time to look at your issue but haven't sorry, so I'm providing this alternative.